# AngularJS ng-click to go to view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, angularjs-ng-click

Hi I have a button that I have a ng-click directive on that I just want to load a view.  I've looked at some pages online, and I'm not able to figure out how to get the button to work.  My button looks like this:

```
<button class="btn default-btn lookupbtn" ng-click="go('/lookup')">Lookup</button>
```

and my controller like this:

```
(function () {

'use strict';

angular.module('crm.ma').controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl, function($location){


    function LookUpCtrl() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.results = [
            {
                accountId: 1,
                accountName: 'some name',
                address: '201 some st',
                city: 'Columbus',
                state: 'OH',
                zip: 'zip',
                phone: '899-629-7645',
                parentName: 'Parent 1',
                accountType: 'Type 1',
                accountStatus: 'Status 1',
                creditTerm: 'Term 1'
            },
            {
                accountId: 2,
                accountName: 'house home',
                address: '2963 this st',
                city: 'Columbus',
                state: 'OH',
                zip: 'zip',
                phone: '899-627-7592',
                parentName: 'Parent 2',
                accountType: 'Type 2',
                accountStatus: 'Status 2',
                creditTerm: 'Term 2'
            }
        ];

        vm.go = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        };

    }        
})

}());
```

I'm really new to Angular and I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.  If any other code is needed please let me know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that you could convert that button to anchor & apply the CSS classes of `button` of bootstrap, that will give you look and fill of button it & then use `ng-href` attribute to have redirection URL on it inside SPA.

```
<a class="btn btn-md" ng-href="#/lookup">Lookup</a>
```

Additionally as @charlietfl suggested you need to add missing dependency of `$location`, `$scope` would also needs to add if you are following the second way.

Comment: @hollyquinn Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Controller definition is incorrect. Should look like:

```
angular
  .module('crm.ma')
  // only 2 arguments, name and function
  .controller('LookUpCtrl', LookUpCtrl);

    // add the dependency injections to function
    function LookUpCtrl($location) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.results = [... ];

        vm.go = function (path) {
            $location.path(path);
        };

    }
```

Then for `go()` you have no function `go()` in your controller and if you did you wouldn't use a leading `/` for `$state.go()`

Can use `ui-sref` to point to a state in html if using `ui-router`:

```
<a class="btn btn-md" ui-sref="lookup">Lookup</a>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is also very helpful.